# Replace all dots to single

Tags: javascript, regex, regular-language

How to replace

```
. . . Hello . . . . . . world . . .
```

to

```
. Hello . world .
```

replace "point space point" by simply point

Tried it like this:

```
/(\.\s\.)+/i
```

Comment: Does the string begin and end in a space, or are those extra spaces inserted by the replacer?

Comment: @CertainPerformance input string may begin, result without spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can phrase the replacement as being any single dot, which in turn is followed by a space and another dot, that entire quantity occurring one or more times.  That is, we can find on the following pattern and then replace with just a single dot:

```
\.( \.)+
```

Code sample:

```js
var input = ". . . Hello . . . . . . world . . .";
console.log(input);
input = input.replace(/\.( \.)+/g, ".");
console.log(input);
```

**Edit:**

We could make the pattern slightly more efficient by turning off capturing using `?:`, i.e. use the following pattern:

```
\.(?: \.)+
```

Comment: Your code looks shorter and the answer is more explanatory. The first answer uses construction `?:`, as far as I understand it is not necessary?

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько The pattern `\.(?: \.)+` just tells the regex engine _not_ to capture what is inside the `()`.  So, it might make the replacement _slightly_ more efficient.  I chose not to include it, but you may do so if you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
/\.(?: \.)+/
```

Match a period, then repeat a group of a space followed by a period as many times as possible, and replace it all with a single period.

```js
const str = '. . . Hello . . . . . . world . . .';
console.log(
  str.replace(/\.(?: \.)+/g, '.')
);
```